# jQuery - Non-nested / non-descendant sibling navigation shown on hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouse

I have 2 navigation areas. The second should appear when an element in the first is hovered over and it should disappear if the mouse does not move over it.

Very basically i have:

HTML

```html
<ul class="main">
 <li class="1">item 1</li>
 <li class="2">item 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="sub">
 <ul class="1">
  <li>1 sub item 1</li>
  <li>1 sub item 2</li>
 </ul>

 <ul class="2">
  <li>2 sub item 1</li>
  <li>2 sub item 2</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I want ul.1 to appear when I hover over li.1 and ul.2 to appear when I hover over li.2, and I want them both to disappear only when I am not hovering over the sub uls.

I've got it working part way:

JAVASCRIPT

```js
var sections = new Array('1', '2');

$.each(sections, function(i, section) {
    $('ul.main li.' + section).hover(
        function() {
            $('div.sub ul').hide();
            $('div.sub ul.' + section).show();
        }
    );
});
```

This will show the correct section and hide the others, but I can't figure out how what I need so that, when the mouse moves off a ul.main li, the .sub ul disappears if it's not being hovered over.

**Update:** *Fiddle here:* http://jsfiddle.net/alluvialplains/XY4mH/

Comment: Why aren't you nesting the sub menus inside of the main menu? That would fix your problem.

Comment: I'm not nesting because the sub navs need to push the later content down, but they also need to be wider than the main nav, which means absolute positioning and no content-pushing :-(

Comment: The key elements you're missing are: #1) A wrapping div to bind a `mouseleave` event to, and #2) You're using `.hover()` but this is more easily achieved with a wrapper div with a `.hide()` event bound to it.  See my answer below for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're part of the way there @EpF. The problem is that your semantic example given above (which is possible to adhere to) is trying to capture a `mouseleave` event and while it's possible to use jQuery's [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function to achieve this, it would be expensive.  Really, the smartest way to do this is to have an outer wrapper for your whole navigation (wrapping all div's you've got in your existing fiddle) and then bind your `show()` event to `mouseenter`, while separately binding your `.hide()` event (the one for ALL `.subz`) to an event triggered on `mouseleave` for the wrapper div.

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="mainz">
     <li class="1">item 1</li>
     <li class="2">item 2</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="subz">
     <ul class="1">
      <li>1 sub item 1</li>
      <li>1 sub item 2</li>
     </ul>

     <ul class="2">
      <li>2 sub item 1</li>
      <li>2 sub item 2</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- /END #nav-wrap -->
```

You can achieve the effect with the following javascript

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    var $ul = $( '.subz ul' ).hide();
    $( '.mainz li' ).on( 'mouseenter', function(event){
            $ul.hide().eq( $( this ).index() ).show();
    });
    $( '#nav-wrap' ).on( 'mouseleave', function(event){
        $ul.hide();
    });
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/XY4mH/4/

Also, I should note that the `.hover()` function is deprecated in jQuery for quite a while now and could disappear sometime soon.  Note that I used the `.on()` function, which is the correct way to bind these kinds of events in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks @Brian! I appreciate the .hover() info too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
  $( '.main li' ).on( 'click', function () {
    $( '.sub ul' )
      .hide()
      .eq( $( this ).index() )
        .show();
  });
});
```

That should do the trick. But as @Mottie said, nesting menus would work better / more symantecly

Edit: Sorry this is working on `click`. Just a sec and I'll have it updated

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    var $ul = $( '.sub ul' ).hide();
    $( '.main li' ).hover(
        function () {
            $ul
                .hide()
                .eq( $( this ).index() )
                    .show();
        },
        function () {
            $ul.hide()
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks @James - I probably wasn't clear enough in my question, but these 2 elements are above one another (.main and .sub), and what I'm trying to achieve is to be able to hover over .main li.1 and then hover over .sub ul.1, which isn't working with your suggestion (.sub ul.1 disappears). I only want the .sub ul to disappear if the user moves the mouse off .main li but **not** onto .sub ul